# simple matrix type rotation (without numpy or pandas)

Tags: python

This must be something that is really simple, but I could not fix it.

I want to do a matrix type transpose with native python list of list (i.e., without using `numpy` or `pandas`). Code is show following. I am having a hard time trying to figure out where it is wrong.

```
raw_matrix_list = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]

def rotate_matrix_list(raw_matrix_list):
    rows = len(raw_matrix_list)
    cols = len(raw_matrix_list[0])
    new_matrix_list = [[0] * rows] * cols
    for ii in xrange(cols):
        for jj in xrange(rows):
#             print str(ii) + ', ' + str(jj) + ', ' + str(rows)
            new_matrix_list[ii][jj] = raw_matrix_list[rows-jj - 1][ii]
    return(new_matrix_list)

rotate_matrix_list(raw_matrix_list)
```

The result I get is

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

What I want to get is:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

===

```
$ python --version
```

Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

===

## update 2

Now I got the answer of how to do it in python with `zip` function. But I just failed to see why my code did not work.

Comment: Could you post what you expect to get in this example?

Comment: updated above, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, doing a transpose with vanilla lists in Python is pretty easy: use `zip` and the splat operator:

```
>>> raw_matrix_list = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
...                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
...                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
>>> transpose = list(zip(*raw_matrix_list))
>>> transpose
[(1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(transpose)
[(1, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 1)]
```

For python 2, you only need `zip(*raw_matrix_list))` rather than `list(zip(*raw_matrix_list)))`

If a list of tuples won't do:

```
>>> transpose = [list(t) for t in zip(*raw_matrix_list)]
>>> pprint(transpose)
[[1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

The problem with your solution is that you use:

```
new_matrix_list = [[0] * rows] * cols
```

This makes every list the *same object*. 
See this example for the problem:

```
>>> x = [[0]*3] * 4
>>> x
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> x[0][0] = 1
>>> x
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Use something like:

```
new_matrix_list = [[0 for _ in range(rows)] for _ in range(cols)]
```

And you should be well on your way.

Comment: Thanks for your elegant answer, I am marking it as accepted. But what drives me crazy is why my code just does not work. Could you help on that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested list comprehension:

```
rows, cols = len(raw_matrix_list), len(raw_matrix_list[0])

>>> [[raw_matrix_list[i][j] for i in range(rows)] for j in range(cols)]
[[1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers that help solve your problem. As to why your code doesn't work, shouldn't it be this (by definition of matrix transpose):

`new_matrix_list[ii][jj] = raw_matrix_list[jj][ii]`